# Bootstrap dropdown not working in some views

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, sinatra, erb

I am struggling to get my dropdown menu to function properly. I pulled the template for the dropdown straight from the Twitter Bootstrap guide(v3) and tweaked it for my purposes. The app is built in Sinatra, and the code for the dropdown resides in my layout view. The menu works properly from any views the are on the same level as layout, but when clicking on the dropdown from any view located in a subdirectory, clicking it just appends a `#` to the end of the URL and the menu does not drop down.

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-target="#" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Campaigns  <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <% current_user.campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
        <li><a href="/campaigns/<%= campaign.slug %>"><%= campaign.name %></a></li>
        <% end %>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/campaigns/new">New Campaign</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: show us a working snippet

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, so I apologize for the oversight. However I do not seem to be able to get the snippet to run properly since my views are coded in erb and not raw HTML. If I am missing something, please let me know!

Comment: Put whatever you got, I will fix it and make it work

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. What else would you want to see in order to get a better idea of what the issue is? The snippet I posted originally works from any view residing directly inside of my /views directory (where my layout.erb resides as well). The dropdown no longer functions from any view that is in any subdirectory of /views. The goal is to have a single level dropdown in the navbar, accessible from any page, that generates its <li>s dynamically from the current user's campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for multi level dropdown, if that's what you are looking for.

Substitute your dropdown data into this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">List 1</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">List 2</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```